How to resolve componentInstance issue in angular unit test case
In my angular 18 application for the unit test, Just i am trying to call the function to veify in the spec file. But It is not working. I am getting below the error.
How to resolve this error.
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'componentInstance')

app.component.spec.ts:
import {
  TestBed,
  ComponentFixture
} from '@angular/core/testing';
import { provideMockStore } from '@ngrx/store/testing';
import { MyInputComponent } from './my-input.component';
import { FormBuilder, ReactiveFormsModule, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

describe('MyInputComponent', () => {
  let component: MyInputComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyInputComponent>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [ReactiveFormsModule, provideMockStore()],
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyInputComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });


  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should call addNumber', () => {
    component.addNumber(); //Getting componentInstance Error 
    expect(component.addNumber).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

});

app.component.ts:
addNumber(){

let a = 5;
let b = 19;
return a+b;

}


Based on the angular documentation, the only difference that I could see is that on the docs, they use waitForAsync instead of declaring directly an asynchronous function when configuring the testModule.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Let's declare your component when creating the testing module
describe('MyInputComponent', () => {
  let component: MyInputComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyInputComponent>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [MyInputComponent], // Declare the component
      providers: [ReactiveFormsModule, provideMockStore()],
    }).compileComponents();
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyInputComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });


  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should call addNumber', () => {
    expect(component.addNumber()).toEqual(24);
  });
});


Added, But not working. Getting same error
